# how can i add a DateTimePicker and ComboBoxes to mysql database then displaying it to DataGridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net

**Form**

```
Sub ViewRecords()
        Try
        read("SELECT * FROM reservation", DataGridView1)
    Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add.Click
        Try
            ComboTIME = (hr.SelectedItem.ToString + ":" + min.SelectedItem.ToString + " " + fr.SelectedItem.ToString)
            write("INSERT INTO reservation (ReservationCode, UserId, RestaurantName, RestaurantLocation, Time, Date, ReservationStatus, Remarks) VALUES ('" & code.Text & "','" & userid.Text & "','" & restoname.Text & "', '" & restolocation.Text & "', '" & datepicker.Value & "', '" & ComboTIME & "', '" & ans & "', '" & remarks.Text & "')")
            code.Clear()
            userid.Clear()
            restoname.Clear()
            restolocation.Clear()
            datepicker.ResetText()
            hr.ResetText()
            min.ResetText()
            fr.ResetText()
            y.ResetText()
            n.ResetText()
            remarks.Clear()
            ViewRecords()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**MODULE CONNECTION**

```
 Public Sub read(ByVal sql As String, ByVal DTG As Object)
    Try
        dt = New DataTable
        con.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = sql
        End With
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        DTG.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & ex.Source, "Load Data Failed")
        con.Close()
    End Try
    con.Close()
    da.Dispose()
End Sub

Public Sub write(ByVal sql As String)

        Try
            con.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                If result = 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("FAILED.")
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS.")
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

> My only problem in my program is that when i click the button the datetimepicker and the comboboxes that i bind and declared as ComboTIME wont record in the database and also in the datagridview, My connection with the database is fine and the TextBoxes were storable and displayable in both database and datagridview, can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Whether the data is saved to the database and whether the data is displayed in a grid are two completely separate issues. For one thing, you haven't shown us any code that displayed the data in a grid. Presumably `ViewRecords` does that but you haven't shown it. Apart from that, that code might be perfect but it won't be useful if there's no data in the database. In the code you have shown, what actually happens? You haven't bothered to tell us whether `result` is 0 or something else or an exception is thrown. If there's no exception and `result` is not 0 then that code is working fine.

Comment: Apart from that, there are significant changes you could make to improve that code. Building SQL code using string concatenation like that is always bad. It might work some of the time - even most of the time - but there are a number of problems that can occur, the most serious of which could allow a malicious user to delete all your data. Learn to use parameters for a start, and also create a destroy all your ADO.NET objects where you use them.

Comment: I wonder how carefully you actually read your own code. In the column list in your SQL code, you have `"Time, Date"` while, in the value list, you have `datepicker.Value & "', '" & ComboTIME`, which appears to be the opposite way around. I suspect that the code you posted is throwing an exception and the message that you didn't provide to us actually indicates this error. If not then that might be even worse, because you might actually be saving bad data, which is worse than failing to save data at all.

Comment: Please stop adding irrelevant tags to your question. This question has nothing to do with C#. Tags are not a way for you to get more eyeballs on your question. They are to tell us whether a question is relevant to us. The C# tag belongs on questions that are specific to C# only.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you sir the twp comboboxes were fixed which is the hr and min while the fr is till results to 00. it is just now the PM & AM results to like this 4:32 00, while the DateTimePicker value still remain a blank cell in the DataGridView1

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry sir

Comment: @Mary, that code was added to the question after I made that comment.

Comment: @jmcilhinney got it. deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Always provide accessibility modifiers to make your code clearer to read. When you start working in multimple languages in multiple evironments it might be difficult to remember whai the default accessibility is in vb.net.

Separate you data access code from your user interface code. For example, you are passing a DataGridView to your module code. Suppose the boss says he really wants to have a web app. Now you not only have to fix your user interface code but you need to modify your module too. Keeping them separate would only require changing the UI code. My `DataAccess` class remains the same.

`Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

`Parameters` help protect against sql injection. A user can enter anything in a text box including "Delete * From reservation" `Parameters` provide only values not executable code so they cannot damage the database. I had to guess at the `SqlDbType` so, you need to check you database for the correct types.

User Interface code...

```
Private Sub ViewRecords()
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Try
        dt = DataAccess.GetReservationData
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox($"Failed to fill grid {ex.Message}")
        Return
    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
Private ans As String = ""

    Private Sub InsertReservation()
    Dim code As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(code.Text, code) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Code needs to be a number.")
        Return
    End If
    Dim userID As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(userid.Text, userID) Then
        MessageBox.Show("User ID needs to be a number.")
        Return
    End If
    Try
        DataAccess.InsertReservation(code, userID, restoname.Text, restolocation.Text, ComboTIME.Text, datepicker.Value, ans, remarks.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show($"Insert Failed {ex.Message}")
            Return
        End Try
        MessageBox.Show("Reservation inserted successfully.")
End Sub
```

Database code...

```
Public Class DataAccess

    Private Shared ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

    Public Shared Function GetReservationData() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM reservation", con)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dt.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub InsertReservation(ReservationCode As Integer, UserID As Integer, RestaurantName As String, Location As String, Time As String, ResDate As Date, Status As String, Remarks As String)
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO reservation (ReservationCode, UserId, RestaurantName, RestaurantLocation, Time, Date, ReservationStatus, Remarks) VALUES (@ResurvationCode, @UserID, @RestaurantName, @Location, @Time, @Date, @Status, @Remarks)", con)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@ReservationCode", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = ReservationCode
                .Add("@UserID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = UserID
                .Add("@RestaurantName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RestaurantName
                .Add("@Location", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Location
                .Add("@Time", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Time
                .Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ResDate
                .Add("@Status", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Status
                .Add("@Remarks", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Remarks
            End With
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```